# how to change css property of 2nd & 6rd DIV using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webforms

I need to display article details like Image, Title, Author, Desc in a matrix of 3x2 format.

I use following `class` to wrap article details

```
#article2x3-article-wrapperHP
{
float:left;
width:233px;
height:340px;
background-color:#ccc;
vertical-align:middle;
margin-right:25px;
}
```

This class has a margin-right: 25px which adds `margin-right:25px;` to every div and it breaks my design and the container has width of `750px` only.

I thought of using jquery to assign `margin-right:0px;` to fix my design but it is not working. How can i fix my jquery so that i can assign    `margin-right: 0px;` to 3rd & 6th DIV using jquery

```
 $(function () {
     $(".article2x3-outer-wrapperHP div:eq(3)").css("margin-right", "0px");
    $(".article2x3-outer-wrapperHP div:eq(6)").css("margin-right", "0px");
 });
```

Below is the sample HTML code for design

```
<div id="article2x3-outer-wrapperHP">

        <div id="article2x3-HPTitle">
            <span id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x4Title">Current Articles</span>
        </div>

        <div id="article2x3-article-wrapperHP">
            <div id="article2x3-image">
                <img src="../images/article/9f07eb06-7f9d-4f68-92e1-d99ea36ebb65.png" class="imgArticle2x3Image" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_imgArticle2x3Image_0">
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-title">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Title" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Title_0">Article One</span>
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-author">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Author" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Author_0">by Author</span>
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-desc">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Desc" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Desc_0">My admiration for the amazing achievemen...</span>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div id="article2x3-article-wrapperHP">
            <div id="article2x3-image">
                <img src="../images/article/9f07eb06-7f9d-4f68-92e1-d99ea36ebb65.png" class="imgArticle2x3Image" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_imgArticle2x3Image_0">
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-title">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Title" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Title_0">Article One</span>
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-author">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Author" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Author_0">by Author</span>
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-desc">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Desc" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Desc_0">My admiration for the amazing achievemen...</span>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div id="article2x3-article-wrapperHP">
            <div id="article2x3-image">
                <img src="../images/article/9f07eb06-7f9d-4f68-92e1-d99ea36ebb65.png" class="imgArticle2x3Image" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_imgArticle2x3Image_0">
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-title">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Title" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Title_0">Article One</span>
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-author">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Author" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Author_0">by Author</span>
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-desc">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Desc" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Desc_0">My admiration for the amazing achievemen...</span>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div id="article2x3-article-wrapperHP">
            <div id="article2x3-image">
                <img src="../images/article/9f07eb06-7f9d-4f68-92e1-d99ea36ebb65.png" class="imgArticle2x3Image" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_imgArticle2x3Image_0">
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-title">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Title" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Title_0">Article One</span>
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-author">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Author" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Author_0">by Author</span>
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-desc">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Desc" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Desc_0">My admiration for the amazing achievemen...</span>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div id="article2x3-article-wrapperHP">
            <div id="article2x3-image">
                <img src="../images/article/9f07eb06-7f9d-4f68-92e1-d99ea36ebb65.png" class="imgArticle2x3Image" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_imgArticle2x3Image_0">
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-title">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Title" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Title_0">Article One</span>
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-author">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Author" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Author_0">by Author</span>
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-desc">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Desc" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Desc_0">My admiration for the amazing achievemen...</span>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div id="article2x3-article-wrapperHP">
            <div id="article2x3-image">
                <img src="../images/article/9f07eb06-7f9d-4f68-92e1-d99ea36ebb65.png" class="imgArticle2x3Image" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_imgArticle2x3Image_0">
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-title">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Title" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Title_0">Article One</span>
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-author">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Author" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Author_0">by Author</span>
            </div>
            <div id="article2x3-desc">
                <span class="lblArticle2x3Desc" id="MainContent_LatestTopSixArticles_rptTopSixArticles_lblArticle2x3Desc_0">My admiration for the amazing achievemen...</span>
            </div>
        </div>  

</div>
```

I actual web page is asp.net-webform & i am using repeater control to create this div & i dont want to do it in .cs file to as it is more convenient a get it done in front end using jQuery

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yJSdP/)

Comment: U can use templates for jquery for repeating elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: Managed To make it work with following jQuery

```
 $(function () {
   //  $(".article2x3-article-wrapperHP:eq(3)").css("margin-right", "0px");
     $('#article2x3-article-wrapperHP:nth-child(3n+1)').css('margin-right', '0px');
     $('#article2x3-article-wrapperHP:nth-child(6n+1)').css('margin-right', '0px');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(function () {
     $(".article2x3-article-wrapperHP:eq(3)").css("margin-right", "0px");
    $(".article2x3-article-wrapperHP:eq(6)").css("margin-right", "0px");
 });
```

without div ... cause you actually tell him to set margin of the inner div .. not the main.

edit: you might use that if this effect occurs on every 3th element:

```
$('.article2x3-article-wrapperHP:nth-child(3n)').css("margin-right", "0px");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `:nth-child()` selector instead. http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Also note that using multiple of the same `id` on a page is invalid. If you change the `id`s to `class`es and accordingly change each `#` to `.` in your CSS and jQuery selectors, you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Change `#article2x3-article-wrapperHP` to `.article2x3-article-wrapperHP` in your css file.

Change `id="article2x3-article-wrapperHP"` to `class="article2x3-article-wrapperHP" in your html file.`

And use as script this:

```
$(function () {
  $(".article2x3-article-wrapperHP:nth-child(4)").css("marginRight", "0px");
  $(".article2x3-article-wrapperHP:nth-child(7)").css("marginRight", "0px");
});
```

Worked for me!